# How does IES compare versus AES and RSA?

Tags: aes, ecies

How does IES compare versus AES and RSA in terms of speed and security?

Comment: What _precisely_ do you mean by "IES" (DHIES, ECIES? which symmetric algorithms used?) and what _precisely_ do you mean with "AES and RSA"? These kinds of details matter for speed-comparisons and benchmarks. Also your target plaintext size matters a lot (i.e. RSA-KEM + AES-GCM can be just about as fast as ECIES with AES-GCM for really large plaintexts if the AES computations dominate computation time).

Comment: @SEJPM I’d assume the question is IFC(DH) IES using AES, ECIES using AES and then either Enveloped CMS or direct RSA(key)+AES. Clock(Encrypt), Clock(Decrypt), BytesOverWire, weakest point BitsOfSecurity; 3 (or 4) way grudge match. (Admittedly, still a little vague, since the asymmetric key sizes are the limiting factor for a while)